# Is this procedure right for finding cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have two independent random variables $X,Y$. We are interested in finding the following probability $$P\left(X+Y<c_1\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]+c_2\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]\right)$$ In one of the  paper they used the CDF of $X+Y$ ($F_{X+Y}(z)$)to find it in following way $$P\left(X+Y<c_1\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]+c_2\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]\right)=E\left[F_{X+Y}\left(c_1\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]+c_2\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]\right)\right]$$ where the expectation on the right side is with respect to $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $\frac{Y}{X+Y}$. Is this right way to find the above probability?

Comment: Can you link the paper please? To answer your question: this is correct but needs independence, i.e. that $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is independent of $X+Y$.

Comment: here is the link of that paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5687v1.pdf . If you see equation 36 then you can see that there they have presented something like my post ($X=u,Y=v,c=\beta$ and the other two variables ($I's$) are 1 in my post.) Eq (36) is from Eq. 35 and Eq. 31 nd Eq. 32 are also used

Comment: What do the brackets stand for?

Comment: @JimmyR. the expression on the right of inequality is single expression.Brackets can be removed for convenience

Comment: But then the RHS is equal to $c \cdot\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}=c$. What am I missing?

Comment: @air I think in the discussion just above Eq 35 they mention about some indpendence but I am not sure if they are saying the same thing as you are saying

Comment: @JimmyR. corrected. Thanks for your comment